# MySQL Workbench: Beautify/Reformat option doesn't work when I write stored procedures

Tags: mysql-workbench

I recently installed MySQL Workbench 6.3. When I write queries the Beautify/Reformat option works fine. But that's not the case when I write stored procedures. If I click the corresponding button nothing happens and also the menu in Edit -> Format is inactive. Since it is a useful feature I would be very grateful if someone could give information about this issue. Is it probably related to the specific version of MySQL Workbench or are there any settings that should be altered, etc.?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like the beautify command is not enabled there (or got disconnected). Can you open a bug report at https://bugs.mysql.com to get this fixed?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After filing a bug report at bugs.mysql.com it was confirmed that the problem was associated with the specific build of the MySQL Workbench 6.3 which was not the last one. This problem does not exist in later versions, for example the current newest version which is 8.0.13.